# convex conjugate of logistic regression

Tags: convex-optimization, machine-learning

For a convex function $f(x)$, its conjugate is defined as 
$$
f^*(z) = \sup_x \; x^Tz - f(x).
$$
For the function $f(x) = \log(1+e^{-x})$, there exists a closed-form solution for $f^*$. But, for a realistic logistic regression case, 
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^m \log(1+e^{-a_i^Tx}).
$$
Is there an easy way to compute the conjugate $f^*(z)$ given some $z$? Or do I need to solve an optimization problem numerically to get a solution?

**Edit**: I now have a partial answer to a related problem, which was the reason I was looking for this in the first place. It's not an exact answer to the posed question though.

Fenchel duality tells us the following two problems are duals:
$$
p^{*}=\inf _{x\in X}\{f(Ax) + g(x)\},\qquad
d^{*}=\sup _{y\in Y}\{-f^{*}(-y)-g^{*}(A^Ty)\}.
$$
So, take $f(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^m \underbrace{\log(1+\exp(-\theta_i))}_{f_i(\theta_i)}$. Then the conjugate of this guy is

$$
f^*(\nu) = \sum_{i=1}^m f_i^*(\nu_i) = \sum_{i=1}^m\log(-\nu^{-1}-1)
$$
with an implicit constraint that $-1<\nu<0$.

So, while this doesn't tell you exactly how to compute the conjugate of $f$, it does tell you how to deal with finding dual problems involving logistic regression and some kind of regularization. However, I do find the implicit constraint unsatisfying... it seems to be asking a lot for dual feasibility.

Answer (score 4):

Derive convex conjugate for function:
\begin{equation}
f_i (x) = log(1+e^{-y_ix})
\end{equation}
where $y_i$ can be in $\{+1,-1\}$.
\
The conjugate of a function is defined as:
\begin{equation}
f^*(x) := \max_{x} x^Ty-f(x)
\end{equation}

**{Case(1) }: $y_i = -1$**
Plug function (1) inside for first case:
\begin{align}
f^*(y) := \max_{x} x^Ty-log(1+e^{x})
\end{align}
To Find the maximum, we derive w.r.t x and equate to zero:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial (x^Ty-log(1+e^{x})) }{\partial x} &= y - \frac{e^x}{1+e^x} = 0\\
y&= \frac{e^x}{1+e^x}\\
\end{align}
Take log of both side:
\begin{align}
log(y) &= x - log(1+e^x) = x - f(x)\\
x^* &= log(y) +f(x)
\end{align}
Note also that :
\begin{align}
1 - y &= 1- \frac{e^x}{1+e^x}\\
1-y &= \frac{1}{1+e^x}\\
\end{align}

Take log of both side:
\begin{align}
log(1-y) = -log(1+e^x) = -f(x)
\end{align}
Plug into original equation the value of $x^{*}$:
\begin{align*}
f^*(y) =& (log(y) +f(x))^Ty-f(x)\\
f^*(y) =& log(y)^Ty +f(x)^T(y-1)\\
\text{Plug f(x) = -log(1-y):}&\\
f^*(y) =& log(y)^Ty +log(1-y)^T(1-y)\\
\end{align*}
$y \in (0,1)$
\

**Case(2): $y_i = 1$**
\begin{align}
f^*(y) := \max_{x} x^Ty-log(1+e^{-x})
\end{align}
To Find the maximum, we derive w.r.t x and equate to zero:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial (x^Ty-log(1+e^{-x})) }{\partial x} &= y - \frac{-e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} = 0\\
-y&= \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}\\
\text{Take log of both side:}&\\
log(-y) &= -x - log(1+e^{-x}) = -x - f(x)\\
x^* &= -log(-y) - f(x)
\end{align}
Note also that :
\begin{align}
1 -(- y) &= 1- (+  \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}})\\
1+ y &= \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\\
\text{Take log of both side:}&\\
log(1+y) = - log(1+e^{-x}) =-f(x)
\end{align}
Finally plug back the value of $x^*$:
\begin{align*}
f^*(y) =& (-log(-y) - f(x))^Ty-f(x) \\
f^*(y) =& -log(-y)^Ty -f(x)^T(y+1) \\
\end{align*}
Plug $f(x) = -log(1+y)$

\begin{align*}
f^*(y) =& -log(-y)^Ty +log(1+y)^T(y+1) \\
\end{align*}
$y \in (-1,0)$